# How to inject a private field in a Component class while keep initiating with @Autowired in parent class in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am learning Spring while I like the idea of using @Component and @Autowired to let Spring manage the dependent bean. For example, I have a Service class and Builder Class I can do with

```
// SomeService.java
@Service
public class SomeService {
    // SomeBuilder is a @Component class
    @Autowired
    SomeBuilder someBuilder;
}

// SomeController.java
@Component
public class SomeController {
    @Autowired
    SomeService someSerivce;
}
```

Spring would take care of the creation of from SomeController to SomeService to SomeBuilder with the usage of @Autowired. However, now my SomeService class needs a private field which is NOT a Component class, just a plain context object, for example

```
// SomeService.java
@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    SomeBuilder someBuilder;
    
    private SomeContext someContext;

    // Plan A: Using constructor to initiate the private field. However, I cannot use @Autowired to initiate SomeService in SomeController anymore as it requires a parameterless constructor
    // Plan B: using @Autowired on constructor level, I cannot use this because SomeContext is not a @Component class
    //public SomeService(SomeContext someContext) {
        //this.someContext = someContext;
    //}
    
    // Plan C: This seems work but I kinda feel it's not the right way, as usually private field are initiated through constructor
    //public void init(SomeContext someContext) {
        // this.someContext = someContext;
    //}
    
    // demo usage of someContext
    public someAnswer realMethod() {
        System.out.println(someContext.getName());
    }
}
```

Now I have no idea how to inject the someContext now, I used

plan A: Assign the private field using class constructor

plan B: Using @Autowired on constructor level

plan C: Using a wired method to assign the private field.

but I am not satisfied and don't have a clear way of doing the right approach.

Comment: This is what constructors are for. Use them instead of field injection. (In the case of "I need a value that's not a bean", you can use an `@Bean` method.)

Comment: Is there any example that I can refer? I am not an expert to use with Bean annotation for now, are you suggesting put the `@Bean` on my `init` method or somewhere else?

Comment: `@Bean` methods go in `@Configuration` classes. The feature set you're looking for was called JavaConfig when it was new in 3.0 but is now just the standard way to configure Spring contexts.

Comment: The fact that a field is `private` doesn't mean it has to be initialized through the constructor, that train of thought is just wrong. Basically all your fields should be `private` als the `@Autowired` ones (well you are probably better of by using constructor injection as that is more clear then hidden fields).Why wouldn't `SomeContext` be a bean? What is your definition of a bean? Another thing using `@Autowired` in your controller and not having a no-args constructor has nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets take a look at your plans and bust some myths/misunderstandings.

> Plan A: Using constructor to initiate the private field. However, I cannot use `@Autowired` to initiate `SomeService` in `SomeController` anymore as it requires a parameterless constructor

Great plan, and the way to go. `@Autowired` doesn't depend on having a default constructor. It only indicates that you want the field to be injected with an object of that type. How that object comes to live (default constructor, constructor with arguments) doesn't matter for `@Autowired`. So that part of your understanding is just wrong.

> using `@Autowired` on constructor level, I cannot use this because `SomeContext` is not a `@Component` class

If there is just a single constructor in a bean Spring will automatically use that to satisfy the dependencies. So in this case you don't need `@Autowired`. A bean doesn't have to be an `@Component`, a bean is just an instance of a class available to the application context. One way of achieving that is by marking it as an `@Component` but there are other ways as well. Like defining an `@Bean` method in in an `@Configuration` class to construct the bean.

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("your.base.package")
public class YourConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SomeContext someContext() {
    return new SomeContext();
  }
}
```

Something along those lines. It will detect the `@Component` annotated classes through the `@ComponentScan` and will create a bean of type `SomeContext` for use as a bean.

> Plan C: This seems work but I kinda feel it's not the right way, as usually `private` field are initiated through constructor

All your fields should be `private` not just the ones initialized in a constructor, so also the `@Autowired` ones. You don't want those fields to be, easily, accessible from the outside so they can be modified. So make them `private`.

That all being said, go with constructor injection over field injection or setters/methods for injection. It is clearer and less hidden than field injection and the way to go for mandatory dependencies (for optional dependencies you can use a setter/method).

So using the above config and below classes, it should "just work (tm)".

```java
// SomeService.java
@Service
public class SomeService {
  // SomeBuilder is a @Component class  
  private final SomeBuilder someBuilder;
  private final SomeContext someContext;
  public SomeService(SomeBuilder someBuilder, SomeContext someContext) {
    this.someBuilder=someBuilder;
    this.someContext=someContext;
  }
}

// SomeController.java
@Component
public class SomeController {

  private final SomeService someSerivce;

  public SomeController(SomeService someService) {
    this.someService=someService;
  }
}
```

Comment: Like your defined `@Bean of SomeContext` is just returning a `new SomeContext()`, but I also need to set a lot of fields/properties of SomeContext...If I do `@Bean public SomeContext someContext(String name, Date createDate) { ... }` then how could I call it that returning me a completed someContext and then inject it into SomeService?

Comment: I found out I can use `prototype` and `beanFactory` to initiate my `@Bean SomeContext` during runtime, however, after I created my `SomeContext`, how could I inject it into `SomeService` without using the constructor of `SomeService`?

Comment: I took some additional research on the Spring DI, per my understanding:
To use a Field DI on a private field, that field needs to be either a component class with parameterless constructor, or it could have a constructor but its member are same as component class that Spring can handle the initialization without a non-dependent field. This might not be applicable for a bean or class that needs to be created during run-time. So my request of still using as field DI might not be available here

Comment: It is perfectly capable and either your sources are wrong or your understanding. How a bean comes to existence doesn't matter for an `@Autowired` field/constructor/method. Nothing is prescribing that an `@Autowired` fields type needs to have a no-args (aka default) constructor. There is one thing, which is that if you use component-scanning there has to be a single constructor for use with autowiring, this can be just a single constructor in a class **or** a constructor marked with `@Autowired`.